# Setting up a Structured Light Stereo system

Tags: cameras, stereo-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I am trying to get started with a stereo experiment and wanted to know the mistakes I might have made during the experiment. The goal is to calculate the depth map of an object using one light projector and one camera mounted in a stereo configuration.

I have a DLP 4500 lightcrafter of resolution ‎912x1140 made by Texas Instruments and a camera of resolution 600x800. I am planning to use triangulation methods to estimate the depth. This is how I have setup the components.

1) The experiment is conducted in an enclosure to eliminate effects of ambient light.

2) The structured light pattern that has to be projected onto the object  is loaded as an image. The image is projected onto one of the walls of the enclosure. The projector lens is focused until the projection is clear and the projector is moved backwards or forwards until the projection fits within the boundaries of the face of the enclosure that the projector projects on.

3) The camera is mounted on an adjustable stand with all six degrees of freedom. It is adjusted facing the projection. I am unsure about this part-The camera is placed in the same vertical line as the lens of projector.  The camera is placed above the projector at a distance of about 15 cm. This would be the baseline b for the triangulation formula.

4) The lens of the camera is adjusted until the image observed in the camera is sharp and the entire object and some part of the projected image is made to appear in the frame of the camera.

5) The camera is calibrated using a checkerboard in ROS. The camera intrinsics matrix is generated and thus the focal length f required for the triangulation formula is obtained.

Is this setup okay for the experiment? Have I made a mistake at some stage. I am new to computer vision and may have overlooked some aspects. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds good to me but there are some missing stages.

1. camera to the projector extrinsic calibration
2. projector intrinsic calibration
   -> don't need this stage if you are not interested in the accuracy of your result.

Also, you need to make sure to calibrate camera after adjusting focus. Extrinsic as well if you have made a change in camera-to-projector distance or angle.

Comment: 1. Doesn't the checkerboard  calibration calibrate both the extrinsics and the intrinsics?

Comment: 2. The display from the projector doesn't appear warped. Doesn't it mean the projector intrinsics have already been accounted for?

Comment: extrinsic in the camera calibration is checkerboard to camera. you need to find camera to projector as well.

Comment: any projector image should not look distorted. if TI offers the norminal intrinsic values, it will be fine. don't you need to know the projector intirnsic for the trigonometry?

Comment: 1. Oh! I am assuming by extrinsics of camera to projector you mean the rotation and translation of camera wrt to the projector. I've taken care of the rotation extrinsic by using a spirit level thus making their relative rotations zero. I am not sure how to maintain the translatory component though.(contd)

Comment: 1. (contd)The z component here would be the baseline.I would want the x and y offset to be zero, so that the projector and camera centers lie in the same plane, but I am confused about how to take these measurements. The x and y offset has to be between camera center and projector centers and I am not sure about how to access them.

Comment: 2. I don't think I need them in my case. I've not come across projector intrinsics and can't seem to understand their purpose. I tried googling for it but don't really see where it falls in the scheme of things. Please share If you have any source that I could read.

Comment: 1. The transformation cam wrt projector is normally found by a calibration. Project a chessboard pattern through the projector and localize the camera using the projector image. And this is why you need the projector intrinsic. But you can do it in your way if you don't care about the accuracy.

Comment: 2. I am not sure what kind of decoding method you have in mind but this tutorial is generally very helpful. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220720451_Build_your_own_3D_scanner_Optical_triangulation_for_beginners

Comment: what kind of pattern are you going to use? if you want to try a very basic one, you might need to project a single line onto the object. Then, by solving ray to plain(from the line) intersection you can calculate the depth. To recover the plain equation from the plane you need the projector intrinsic.

Comment: I remember there are some open source 3d structured light scanner codes. I suggest you to have a look at them and run them to see what you need to port the algorithm on your device.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that pdf and for answering my queries. I'll read it first and then proceed.